# What is 'light' in Tolkien's lore, exactly?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

'Light' as a concept seems confusing, since it can possibly encompass (or just be supplied in varying amounts by) Eru's Flame Imperishable, the Lamps of the Valar, the Two Trees, the Silmarils, the sun and moon themselves (only literal light?), the high elves (particularly the amount they're said to have absorbed from the Trees), and possibly even have something to do with the Rings of Power (as surmised from their superficial conceptual similarity to the Silmarils).

Do you think it's possible these concepts (except maybe literal visible light?) are therefore unified as forms/derivations/grades of the Flame Imperishable?

**P.S.** To further complicate matters, why does Tolkien insist on their being 2 "flavors" of light always on prominent display for the entirety of Arda, as noted by the duality of the Lamps, the Trees, and the sun and moon? The latter of course corresponds to day cycles, which are intuitively familiar, but still technically unaccounted for (particularly for the "magical light" context).

**Edit:** Some clarification of this matter can be found here: [If the Lamps of Valinor enabled the Spring of Arda, is their light derived from the Flame Imperishable (Secret Fire)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269447/if-the-lamps-of-valinor-enabled-the-spring-of-arda-is-their-light-derived-from)

Comment: Men thought it was a particle. Elves thought it was a wave. Although they wouldn’t have put it in those terms, Hobbits intuitively understood it was both, which is why they could become invisible.

Comment: Would you clarify the "superficial conceptual similarity" of the Rings of Power to the Silmarils.

Comment: @Eugene Evil and good covet them alike, they exist as discrete artifacts of apparent (material and metaphysical) value, they're very rare, and they're the work of higher powers or crafts that probably not just anyone can perform, or perform repeatedly (or even just more than once).

Comment: Light as a concept is just light. The lamps, the trees, the sun, moon, and starts - they all just produce regular visible light.

Comment: related: [Did the Light of the Trees diminish after the creation of the Silmarils?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252465/did-the-light-of-the-trees-diminish-after-the-creation-of-the-silmarils), [What we we know about the source of the light in the Two Trees of Valinor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149351/what-we-we-know-about-the-source-of-the-light-in-the-two-trees-of-valinor)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149351/what-we-we-know-about-the-source-of-the-light-in-the-two-trees-of-valinor

Comment: Something makes me think that this is somehow connected to Gandalf's anger at Saruman for "breaking the white light".

Comment: @OrangeDog Nope. See "Splintered Light" mentioned in the answer. There's a bit more to it than that.

Comment: @OrangeDog not so: the light of the Trees is liquid and collected in vats. In the Book of Lost Tales it's even more unlike ordinary light.

Comment: I think that you would get different answers if you interrogate Tolkien's works at different periods of his life. The concept of light in the original Book of Lost Tales is vastly different from his ideas from the much later Round World era, when the sun existed from the beginning of Arda.

Comment: @DavidRoberts The question is framed incorrectly.  There is no "exactly" (this is art, this is literature) so asking for that is a non starter.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I took that as rhetoric. In another SE site I'm involved with people sometimes ask questions like "What is X, *really*?", and it's a line of idiom that signals a desire for a deeper understanding, for the sometimes unwritten thoughts that experts have about the topic/object at hand. I'd not dismiss the question out of hand just for a turn of phrase, but treat it as a teaching moment.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I have higher standards.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast and I'm taking the question in good faith :-)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It is an 'exact' question. As per my question's specifications, if there's enough information to infer 'light' is actually a form of Flame Imperishable based on descriptions, and without a clear counter point (despite Tolkien's loose post-commentary), the qualification could apply.

Comment: @hamstar The Flame Imperishable is said to be with Eru, and also that it "burns at the heart of the world"[=Eä] so I find it a stretch to think it was the light of the sun, which was a corrupted, "fallen" form of light. Have you read https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Secret_Fire?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Actually, of all the 'light' sources I listed, the sun would be the most distantly derived instance of this concept. The fact that it exists as derived from the light trees indicates an instance of the derivation concept in effect. This is another reason for why I surmise that most concepts of 'light' may also be such things, with respect to a main/original 'light': The Flame Imperishable.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Here's some relevant clarification: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269447/if-the-lamps-of-valinor-enabled-the-spring-of-arda-is-their-light-derived-from

Comment: As I commented on the other question, I don't believe the Flame Imperishable is ever discussed/treated as a *light* source. We know Tolkien thought of it in spiritual terms, as a source of creative power. But neither Ainulindalë nor Valaquenta say anything about it being a source of light. The former is rather stable over time, so even though I haven't double checked HoMe, I don't expect it to throw up such a discussion in other versions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To give Tolkien's own words about this:

> As far as all this has symbolical or allegorical significance. Light is such a primeval symbol in the nature of the Universe, that it can hardly be analysed. The Light of Valinor (derived from light before any fall) is the light of art undivorced from reason, that sees things both scientifically (or philosophically) and imaginatively (or subcreatively) and says that they are good' – as beautiful. The Light of Sun (or Moon) is derived from the Trees only after they were sullied by Evil.
> <sub>Footnote to a 1951 Letter to Milton Waldman (*Letters of JRR Tolkien* #131)</sub>

For more discussion of the usage of the theme of light in Tolkien's writings see the corresponding entry in Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull's *J.R.R. Tolkien Companion and Guide*, and see Verlyn Flieger's *Splintered Light: Logos and Language in Tolkien World*.

Comment: @hamstar - I quoted it because it's Tolkien's exact words. If I were to try rewriting it it would just be me speaking about the significance of the theme in Tolkien's work, which is the type of openended thing that I think doesn't really fit the nature of this website. (Literature SE might be a better fit. ) But my main takeaway from the quote is that Tolkien is acknowledging there is some allegorical significance to his usage of light.

Comment: So my takeaway is he says it is symbolic/allegorical, but as it's a 'primeval' concept, I guess it gets to be a somehow-intuitive concept who's nature is not meant to be spelled out, or may even vary per circumstance by implicit interpretation.

*My* point, however, is this doesn't seem to actually be the case, as 'light' is all too often represented as a substance, albeit lacking a clear identity. I think the best concept Tolkien provides to infer a possible identity is the Flame Imperishable, due to its properties and rarity.

Comment: I can try to interpret here as I understand it: The Light of Valinor does not just allow one to physically see something, it is the light that allows to "see" both physically and spiritually. To understand and see the beauty of things. After it is sullied with Evil, the light can only illuminate physically. Also he says light as a symbol is so omnipresent in the history of mankind, trying to really analyze it is kind of futile. There is also a biblical aspect here - he seems to allude to the light that was there before the fall, which was there when the creator said the creation was good.

Comment: @kutschkem After the trees were destroyed, their light was destroyed (with possible exception for the Silmarils). Though you'd think a fruit from those trees could make a new tree, instead of simply make the sun. That said, is the sun merely only a 'physical illumination'? Many earth cultures think otherwise, so maybe Tolkien does as well. Also, would the idea of 'seeing spiritually' have something to do with the unseen realm?

Comment: @hamstar No, I mean more like "understanding" a thing, seeing what it really is.

Comment: For some context, this is a footnote connected to this portion of the letter, talking about the Fall of the Elves and the plot/title of *The Silmarillion*: "By the making of gems the sub-creative function of the Elves is chiefly symbolized, but the Silmarilli were more than just beautiful things as such. There was Light. There was the Light of Valinor made visible in the Two Trees of Silver and Gold.\*"